# Zoom out any windows like an image in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, zoom

Is there a program to enlarge or shrink windows below 100% just like an image. e.g. like thumbnail preview when we hover on taskbar?

**It is not magnifier I am asking about** Imagine all your windows are open in a webpage and you can zoom in to enlarge AND zoom out to make all of them smaller than 100% (e.g. using ctrl+scroll) while you can still interact with them.

Long time ago I found a program that can zoom in and zoom out any window with its contents like if it was an image. I was using XP then and had no use of it. Now I can not find it.

Answer (score 0):

On your standard startbar

All Programs >> Accessories >> Ease of Access >> Magnifier

Comment: You can also just type "Magnifer" in the run box after clicking on the Start orb.

Comment: **It is not magnifier I am asking about** Imagine all your windows are open in a webpage and you can zoom in zoom out all of them with ctrl+scroll while you can still interact with them

Comment: Setting the view to "screen mode" sounds similar to what you're asking - I'm using it right now - although you can's zoom via the scroll wheel because the application you're using has focus.

Comment: In fact I want to Zoom Out only, less than 100% of actual. Please edit the question as I think it is not self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for ZoomIt.exe from Sysinternals (now Microsoft). Provides both static zoom (image witout interaction) and dynamic zoom (interaction while zoomed).

Comment: Thanks, it is something near to what I am asking. But in fact I want to Zoom Out only, less than 100% of actual. Please edit the question as I think it is not self explanatory.